# how to insert equal number of values in multiple lists using if-else statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

There is a list of number which contains some random numbers. I am applying conditions to these numbers and doing some calculations and storing the result values in multiple lists. But the only problem that I am facing is that I am not able to store an equal amount of numbers in all lists. Suppose if the condition doesn't fulfill for that list then `0` should be there but this is not happening in my program. In my program, the list of numbers is: `number = [10, 9, 14, 17, -2, -3, 18, 25]`, condition are as follow:

1. if num == 0
2. if 0 < num <= 12
3. if 12 < num <= 15
4. if 15 < num <= 20
5. if num > 20
6. if num < 0

multiple lists are:

```
firstList = []
secondList = []
thirdList = []
forthList = []
fifthList = []
sixthList = []
```

my approach:

```
 number = [10, 9, 14, 17, -2, -3, 18, 25]
firstList = []
secondList = []
thirdList = []
forthList = []
fifthList = []
sixthList = []
for num in number:
    if num ==0:
        firstList.append(0)
    else:
        firstList.append(0)

    if 0 < num <= 12:
        cal = num * 2
        secondList.append(cal)
    else:
        secondList.append(0)

    if 12 <= num <= 15:
        cal = num * 2
        cal2 = num * 4
        secondList.append(cal)
        thirdList.append(cal2)
    else:
        thirdList.append(0)
    if 15 < num <= 20:
        cal = num * 2
        cal2 = num * 4
        cal3 = num * 6
        secondList.append(cal)
        thirdList.append(cal2)
        forthList.append(cal3)
    else:
        forthList.append(0)
    if num > 20:
        cal = num * 2
        cal2 = num * 4
        cal3 = num * 6
        cal4 = num * 4
        secondList.append(cal)
        thirdList.append(cal2)
        forthList.append(cal3)
        fifthList.append(cal4)
    else:
        fifthList.append(0)

        if num < 0:
             cal5 = num * 10
             sixthList.append(cal5)
        else:
            sixthList.append(0)

print("list1: " , firstList)
print("list2: " , secondList)
print("list3: " , thirdList)
print("list4: " , forthList)
print("list5: " , fifthList)
print("list6: " , sixthList)
```

output:

```
list1:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list2:  [20, 18, 0, 28, 0, 34, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 50]
list3:  [0, 0, 56, 0, 68, 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 100]
list4:  [0, 0, 0, 102, 0, 0, 108, 0, 150]
list5:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200]
list6:  [0, 0, 0, 0, -20, -30, 0]
```

Desired Output:

```
list1:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list2:  [20, 18, 28, 34, 0, 0, 36, 50]
list3:  [0, 0, 56, 68, 0, 0, 72, 100]
list4:  [0, 0, 0, 102, 0, 0, 108, 150]
list5:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200]
list6:  [0, 0, 0, 0, -20, -30, 0, 0]
```

Comment: You change approach, for such a task you can generate numbers that come from a specific distribution that have the specifics you impose.

Comment: that's what I am asking, how to do that ?

Comment: after each condition, you want to store  a number in each list?

Comment: Instead of using multiple lists use dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a quick solution, you initialize all the lists with zeros and use the index to update the lists:

```
number = [10, 9, 14, 17, -2, -3, 18, 25]
firstList = [0] * len(number)
secondList = [0] * len(number)
thirdList = [0] * len(number)
forthList = [0] * len(number)
fifthList = [0] * len(number)
sixthList = [0] * len(number)
for i, num in enumerate(number):

# firstList has 0 anyway
#     if num == 0:
#         firstList[i] = 0


    if 0 < num <= 12:
        cal = num * 2
        secondList[i] = cal

    if 12 < num <= 15:
        cal = num * 2
        cal2 = num * 4
        secondList[i] = cal
        thirdList[i] = cal2

    if 15 < num <= 20:
        cal = num * 2
        cal2 = num * 4
        cal3 = num * 6
        secondList[i] = cal
        thirdList[i] = cal2
        forthList [i]= cal3

    if num > 20:
        cal = num * 2
        cal2 = num * 4
        cal3 = num * 6
        cal4 = num * 8
        secondList[i] = cal 
        thirdList[i] = cal2
        forthList[i] = cal3
        fifthList[i] = cal4
    else:
        if num < 0:
            cal5 = num * 10
            sixthList[i] = cal5


print("list1: " , firstList)
print("list2: " , secondList)
print("list3: " , thirdList)
print("list4: " , forthList)
print("list5: " , fifthList)
print("list6: " , sixthList)
```

**output:**

```
list1:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list2:  [20, 18, 28, 34, 0, 0, 36, 50]
list3:  [0, 0, 56, 68, 0, 0, 72, 100]
list4:  [0, 0, 0, 102, 0, 0, 108, 150]
list5:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200]
list6:  [0, 0, 0, 0, -20, -30, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, using list comprehension. Focus on each list first, rather than on the condition. Also note the `else 0` that will fill in with 0 where the condition isn't met.

```
numbers = [10, 9, 14, 17, -2, -3, 18, 25]

firstList = [0]*len(numbers)
secondList = [n*2 if n > 0 else 0 for n in numbers]
thirdList = [n*4 if n>=12 else 0 for n in numbers]
fourthList = [n*6 if n>15 else 0 for n in numbers]
fifthList = [n*4 if n>20 else 0 for n in numbers]
sixthList = [n*10 if n<0 else 0 for n in numbers]

print(firstList)
print(secondList)
print(thirdList)
print(fourthList)
print(fifthList)
print(sixthList)
```

Outputs:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[20, 18, 28, 34, 0, 0, 36, 50]
[0, 0, 56, 68, 0, 0, 72, 100]
[0, 0, 0, 102, 0, 0, 108, 150]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100]
[0, 0, 0, 0, -20, -30, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This won't work in my program because if the number lies between 12  to 15 then I also want to store value in 2nd list and similarly, if the number lies between 15 to 20 then I want to store values in 3rd and 2nd list

Comment: Yeah I got that, what I'm saying is to revert your logic to focus on the list rather than condition. E.g. you store in thirdList if num >= 12

Comment: Edited to include the remaining lists

Comment: Sir, if I apply this approach to my program then it would be something like this: forthList = [n*6 if 12 < n <=15 else 0 for n in numbers]. and this won't give the desired output that I want.

Comment: Check the results. Matches your desired output except for list 5 where I suspect you typed *4 instead of *8.

Comment: @CedricDruck I think you are right, should be an 8 instead of 4

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want numbers from a uniform distribution, which means all the numbers you get have the same probability to come out you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

firstList = [0 for i in range(0,8)]
secondList = np.random.uniform(0,11,8)
thirdList = np.random.uniform(12,14,8)
forthList = np.random.uniform(15,19,8)
fifthList = np.random.uniform(20,1000,8)
sixthList = np.random.uniform(-100,0,8)
```

Samples are uniformly distributed over the half-open **interval [low, high)** (includes low, but excludes high). In other words, any value within the given interval is equally likely to be drawn by uniform.

Comment: this is not what I want. I want numbers according to the condition that I provided

Comment: You mean that the numbers are not integers?

Comment: Numbers are integer but I don't exactly understand how this will help me in my program. Because this won't  give the desired output that I mentioned in question.

Comment: Oh yes, I have missed the recalculation of the numbers